# SuperCSV Cellprocessor that depends on multiple columns

Tags: java, csv, supercsv

I came across the supercsv library and it seems like a very good piece of work.
However I have a question that I wasn't able to answer with the documentation provided in their website, wondering if anyone here can help.

Basically I have a csv file that has a column that only appears when another column is set to a specific value.
So an example would be the following:

IsBirthDate,BirthDate

Yes,11/05/1985

No

Yes,12/01/1999

No

No

You see what I mean. Is there a way to create a cellprocessor that can take this dependency into account and throw an exception when a row like this is found:

No,12/09/1968

Cheers

Comment: Does your CSV file actually have variable columns like the example you've given? Or is there a trailing `,` after each No row?

Comment: It doesn't. So that "No" row is actually "No,". Also wanting to say that I need to do a lot of exception handling on a low level and provide customized detailed reports on why a file is not parsing and due to this I decided to manually write the classes required for parsing the csv file. Library supercsv still looks wonderful though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this has already been answered on the Super CSV forums:
http://sourceforge.net/p/supercsv/feature-requests/25/#30a5

Copying the post in case link goes down:

> I think you're asking whether you can validate that Items have a
>   parentPartNumber but skip that validation for Products. This is
>   essentially cross-validation (validation involving more than 1
>   column).
>
> The only way I can think of to achieve this with cell
>   processors is to write a custom cell processor that inspects the value
>   in another column, and decides what to do based on the value. Every
>   cell processor has access to the `CsvContext`, which contains the raw
>   (unprocessed) values.
>
> So you can write a processor such as the
>   following. It behaves like `Optional` if the value in a given column
>   (where column numbers start at 1) equals the value its expecting.
>   Otherwise, it simply delegates to the next processor in the chain.

```
package example;

import java.util.List;

import org.supercsv.cellprocessor.Optional;
import org.supercsv.cellprocessor.ift.CellProcessor;
import org.supercsv.util.CsvContext;

public class OptionalIfOtherColumnEquals extends Optional {

  private final int column;

  private final Object constantValue;

  public OptionalIfOtherColumnEquals(int column, 
                                     Object constantValue) {
    super();
    this.column = column;
    this.constantValue = constantValue;
  }

  public OptionalIfOtherColumnEquals(int column, 
                                     Object constantValue, 
                                     CellProcessor next) {
    super(next);
    this.column = column;
    this.constantValue = constantValue;
  }

  @Override
  public Object execute(Object value, CsvContext context) {

    // unprocessed row
    List<Object> row = context.getRowSource();

    // optional if other column matches value
    if (row.get(column - 1).equals(constantValue)){
      return super.execute(value, context);
    }

    // otherwise continue to next processor
    return next.execute(value, context);
  }

}
```

> I replaced the processor definition for the parentPartNumber column
>   with new OptionalIfOtherColumnEquals(2, "Product", new
>   IsValueIn(partNumbers)) and it works for Products and Items but it
>   fails validation on the Packages at the end of the file.
>
> I'll leave
>   that as an exercise for you to solve, but you can see that you can
>   achieve cross-validation if you really have to. Hope this helps.